# Is it possible to change value from xaml?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is it possible to change property value from xaml?

Imagine we have a usercontrol which have a property that is initialized already

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...
    public SomeClass MainWindow
    {
         get
         {
              return _someClass ?? (_someClass = new SomeClass();)
         }
    }
}
```

Now is it possible to change property of SomeClass without initializing it from xaml, and without animation?

Why xaml doesn't allow syntax to write `<UserControl.MainWindow.Property>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a setter to the property and allow the XAML to create its own SomeClass according to its need - that's now it is usually done.

XAML is declarative language, it  doesn't try to be Turing complete or something like that, it merely describes **creation** of objects.

Of course, there is one [*extreme* solution](http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/14/yes-you-can-write-inline-code-in-xaml/). But please, don't do it. For your sake, and everyone else's :)

EDIT:

Another solution could be to create a new property in the UserControl, and synchronize this property with property of SomeClass ( `set{ this._someClass.someProperty = value; }`). If you set this property in XAML declaration of the UserControl, the change will be propagated to the _someClass member.

Of course the wrapper property will have to be a dependency property, if you want to bind to the wrapped property.

Comment: are you sure there are no way to change prop value? sure writing code in xaml is not good solution, I can do the same in my UserControl BE, I am just interested is there any other way from xaml, I found animation doing this, but looking for another solutions

Comment: Thanks for post, I guess you are right, there is really no other way, but it may be valuable future, because as far as I can give value to  property, it is  logical to have ability give value of innter property too

Answer (score 0):

One, you need to have a set to change the value.  Two, just bind to it TwoWay in in the XAML.

Comment: I don't want to change the reference to SomeClass @BalamBalam, I want to change property in SomeClass which have setter

Comment: Did you try referring to the property name using Binding Path?

Comment: I don't want ti bind to that property, I want to give static value for example from xaml :)

Comment: XAML is not for for logic.  XAML is a page definition.   Animation does do calculations but it does not have any OO features or real logic.